# Cannot set tab-width in Golang mode with Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, golang

I set the tab-width for Golang to 2 using the following:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-default indent-tabs-mode 1)
            (setq-default tab-width 2)))
```

And when I check the `tab-width` variable, it shows:

```
   tab-width is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
    Its value is 8
    Local in buffer plugin.go; global value is 2

      Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
      This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
      satisfies the predicate ‘integerp’.
```

But when I open any .go file, the tab width is still 8. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/go/README.html) tell you to configure the `go-tab-width` spacemacs layer variable.

In `.spacemacs`, inside `dotspacemacs/layers` is a variable called `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. Add the go layer variables like so:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     (go :variables go-tab-width 2)
   )))
```

Answer (score 2):

`setq-default` sets the *global* value, whereas you want to set the value in your particular go-mode buffer.  Basically, using `setq-default` within a mode-hook is never right.  Try:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode 1)
            (setq tab-width 2)))
```